# Two tables columns interchange draggable and droppable

Tags: javascript, css, html-table

I want to interchange columns in two tables.if "a" is selected and dragged all "1" should move automatically.
http://jsfiddle.net/9LGrm/

```
<table id="a">
    <tr>            
        <td>a</td>        
        <td>b</td>  
        <td>c</td>  
        <td>d</td>  
    </tr>
</table>
<table id="b">
    <tr>            
        <td>1</td>        
        <td>2</td>  
        <td>3</td>  
        <td>4</td>  
    </tr>
     <tr>

        <td>1</td>        
        <td>2</td>  
        <td>3</td>  
        <td>4</td>  
    </tr>

</table>
```

I have tried this plugin:

http://www.danvk.org/wp/dragtable/

https://github.com/jebaird/dragtable

it uses single table I can't change the structure of the table!

Comment: The Fiddle link you provided is blank. Update your fiddle link.

Comment: If you are satisfied with the solution below done by me, you can accept it with a green tick and upvote. Thank you - @Tabraiz Ali

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the [Solution](http://jsfiddle.net/9LGrm/4/).

**The HTML:**

```
    <table class="draggable" id="a"><thead><tr>

<th>a</th>
<th>b</th>
<th>c</th>
<th>d</th>

</tr></thead>
<tbody>
<tr>

<td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td>
<td>4</td>

</tr>
<tr>

<td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td>
<td>4</td>

</tr>
<tr>

<td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td>
<td>4</td>

</tr>



</tbody><tfoot></tfoot></table>
```

**The CSS:**

```
#a
{
 border: 1px black;
}

th{font-weight:normal;}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: i need to do this in two tables

Comment: You cannot start a new table, just after an old table ends, it has to be either inside a separte td or it should be like what I have now as thead and tbody. Plus, I can provide hints on how to do, and you have to build your own solution purely on the logic's used to achieve the solution. So take the logic and make your own solution. Hope this helps. Let me know for queries. - @TabraizAli

Comment: The answer itself. http://jsfiddle.net/9LGrm/4/ The best logic to use thead and tbody with table as the parent to get the solution working. Any specific reason as to why you want to use multiple tables?